# How to control the left and right channel of earphone on Android individually?

Tags: android, audio

I want to make a tricking apps. Does anybody know how to control the left and right channel of earphone on Android individually?

Let me clarify my question: I want to play different sound to left and right channel. Not only control it's volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this link

http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Android:Playing_Sound_Effects_With_SoundPool

you can modify it to have a left and right progress bar and set the volume of left and right individually. I haven't tried it yet. try it out and see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've clarify my question. I want to play different sound to left and right channel. Not only control it's volume.

Comment: @Magic Maybe this sample doesn't show you how play a sound in each channel, but this sample shows you how decrease/increment each channel balance, so with this you can achieve what you want. I think that this answer should be mark as accepted. I had the exact same issue and this solve my problem.